# Internet explorer css with anchor tag

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, hover, anchor

I was checking some posts on this site, but still can't find the solution.
Here's my html:

```
<div id="id1">
  <div id="id2">
    <div id="id3">
      <a id="id4" class="divItem">
        text
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#id1 {
width:960px;
margin:auto;
}

#id2 {
position:relative;
font-family:Calibri;
}

#id3 {
float:right;
position:relative;
margin-bottom:10px;
font-size:12px;
color:#5E666D;
}

.divItem {
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
}

a.divItem:hover {
color:#AD8E5A;
font-size:11px;
}
```

But the hover on divItem doesn't appear in internet explorer, only in safari and firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer 6 can interpret `:hover` only on `a` elements with a `href` attribute. You are missing the attribute.

There's a [fix](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html) that makes `:hover` work as it does in other browsers.

Comment: @Infinity does it work now? Which version of Internet Explorer are we talking about? Can you try `a#id4:hover`?

Comment: how it's possible that your code worked on other browser when you had the extra space?

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan: It was possible, because the extra space was presented only here. Sorry for miss leading post.

Comment: yes, you have right, it needs the href attribute. So do you have any common solution to place the href there, but avoid the effect of it?

Comment: I see you have a link there. Thanks!

Comment: Nice one, Pekka I just came to this conclusion myself, http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/AzgHw/

Comment: @Kyle nice! This is so weird. I mean, what sense does it make to look for the `href` if no other browser cares? Stuff like this is why people rightly hate IE.

Comment: I agree, I hate IE for these reasons. But then developers *should* stop supporting IE6!